ChakraUi/nodejs undefined (reading '_config')
I am new to the chakraUi, I have installed latest npm and chakraUi version. Whenver I try to run my code it gives me this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_config')
at ChakraProvider (provider.js:15:10)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:18)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:13)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:16)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27490:7)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:12)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26505:5)`

Here is my code:
// main.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// App.jsx 
function App() {
    return (
        <h1>Hi</h1>
    );
}

Any leads will be greatly appreciated!!!

I faced same issue today.
Just followed the library here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chakra-ui/provider
import * as React from "react"
import {  Button, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/provider"

const App = () => {
  const theme = {
    // ... your system-ui theme
    config: {
      useSystemColorMode: false, // or true
      initialColorMode: "light", // or "dark"
      cssVarPrefix: "chakra", // any string
    }
  }
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
       ...
     <ChakraProvider>
  );
}

Hope this helps!
Edit:
If this doesn't help, switch to Chakra-ui 2.10.3 version
